# Building a tree from database rows

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree

I need to build a tree from database rows. To be more specific I have a table wich contains the chart of accounts.

Instead of querying the table recursively I want to load all the tables' information, the account rows which contain ids and parentIds in a single step and then build the tree from there.

One of the problems with this is that the account rows are not in any order, ie. I could encounter a child before I encounter the parent.

I reckon that this problem is quite generic so I presume there might even already be a haskell library for it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which database is this? Postgres? Mysql? Oracle? Am I wrong to assume it uses SQL?

Comment: The database is mysql. Unless things have changed a lot with mysql I don't think it can provide me with a hierarichal result, ie. tree and querying the database recursively would work but it would be rather expensive.

Answer (score 2):

As Nikita said, what is your real problem?

You do not provide any data type, tree key classification, ...

Anyway, this code can help to think about your problem...

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving Show

db = [(0, 1)
     ,(1, 2)
     ,(1, 3)
     ,(2, 4)
     ,(2, 6)
     ,(3, 5)
     ]

rootTree = Node 0 []

insert parent child (Node key childs) =
  Node key $ if key == parent then Node child []:childs
                              else map (insert parent child) childs

insertFromDB rows = foldl insertRow rootTree rows
  where insertRow tree (parent, child) = insert parent child tree
```

If you can not get ordered data, you can order it searching parents, next function calculate deep level of each node (with same `db` data)

```
calculateDeepLevel db = compute 0 roots
  where roots = filter (not.flip elem snds) fsts
        fsts = nub $ map fst db
        snds = map snd db
        compute level parents = map (\n -> (n, level)) parents ++
                                concatMap (addChilds (level + 1)) parents
        addChilds level node = compute level $ map snd $ filter ((node==).fst) db
```

with `calculateDeepLevel` you can calculate a ordered `db` version and 0-based from a unordered and no rooted (without 0 node) version of `db`.

Comment: Hi josejuan, thanks for the example. I wasn't able to provide code or a datastructure as an example as the datastructure are not finished yet. The datastructure you provided in your example though is quite sufficient to explain the general principle. The above example works quite well to build the tree, but only if the input data is in order, somthing I might not be able to retrieve from the db. I just tried your code and it works fine, but when I reverted the list it wasn't able to construct the tree. So I'm trying to figure out how to build the tree when the elements come in random order.

Comment: I added `calculateDeepLevel` to get node level, with it, you can order using `sortBy`.

Answer (score 2):

First some imports,

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Tree as T
import Data.List (foldl')
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
```

Next, let's assume we have records that have an id, and an optional parent id (root nodes have no parent), and carry some value:

```
data Rec a = Rec { recId       :: Int
                 , recParentId :: Maybe Int
                 , recValue    :: a
                 }
```

There's nothing to prevent more than one node from having a `Nothing` parent id, so we might find more than one tree, so our function for transforming the list into a tree could look like this:

```
toTree :: [Rec a] -> [T.Tree a]
toTree rs = ts where
```

First, let's build a map from optional parent id to a list of the records that have that parent id:

```
    -- gs :: M.Map (Maybe Int) [Rec a]
    gs = foldl' f M.empty rs where
        f m r = M.insertWith (const (r:)) (recParentId r) [r] m
```

Next, let's unfold a tree starting from a dummy root node, the children of which will be the roots of the trees we're interested in.  Note that the dummy root node has no value, so we use `undefined`:

```
    -- t :: T.Tree a
    t = T.unfoldTree mkNode (undefined, Nothing)
```

The `mkNode` function is passed the value and id of the node we want to build.  It returns the value, and a list of the child value/id pairs using the `Map` we constructed earlier:

```
    -- mkNode :: (a, Maybe Int) -> (a, [(a, Maybe Int)])
    mkNode (a, i) = (a, map (recValue &&& Just . recId)
                          . fromMaybe []
                          . M.lookup i $ gs)
```

Finally, we can discard the dummy root node, and return its immediate children as the roots of the trees we're interested in:

```
    ts = T.subForest t
```

And here's a test:

```
main = mapM_ (putStrLn . T.drawTree)
         $ toTree [ Rec 0 Nothing "rootA"
                  , Rec 1 (Just 0) "rootA.childA"
                  , Rec 2 (Just 0) "rootA.childB"
                  , Rec 3 (Just 1) "rootA.childA.childA"
                  , Rec 4 (Just 1) "rootA.childA.childB"
                  , Rec 5 (Just 2) "rootA.childB.childA"
                  , Rec 6 (Just 2) "rootA.childB.childB"
                  , Rec 7 Nothing "rootB"
                  , Rec 8 (Just 7) "rootB.childA"
                  , Rec 9 (Just 7) "rootB.childB"
                  , Rec 10 (Just 8) "rootB.childA.childA"
                  , Rec 11 (Just 8) "rootB.childA.childB"
                  , Rec 12 (Just 9) "rootB.childB.childA"
                  , Rec 13 (Just 9) "rootB.childB.childB"
                  ]
```

Which generates:

```
rootB
|
+- rootB.childB
|  |
|  +- rootB.childB.childB
|  |
|  `- rootB.childB.childA
|
`- rootB.childA
   |
   +- rootB.childA.childB
   |
   `- rootB.childA.childA

rootA
|
+- rootA.childB
|  |
|  +- rootA.childB.childB
|  |
|  `- rootA.childB.childA
|
`- rootA.childA
   |
   +- rootA.childA.childB
   |
   `- rootA.childA.childA
```

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the answer you get at StackOverflow almost completely depends on the quality of the question you provide. If you want to get an answer containing some code you should provide some code in your question, if you want to get an answer concerning some specific library then refer to it.

Currently your question is very vague, and all I can answer is you need to use a [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html)-like structure to first accumulate the intermediate results and rearrange them after by querying this intermediate data-structure. As it's documentation denotes, the complexity of  most of its accessor functions is `O(log n)`, which is very efficient.

You should not expect that kind of functionality from any database-library, as the problem is too specific.